# How to use vim (key-bindings) with Visual Studio Code vim extension

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, vim-plugin

I just started using Visual Studio Code and think it's really great. 
Also installed the vim extension, but I'm struggling with mapping <kbd>esc</kbd> to a another key.

Normally I have this:

```
:imap jj <Esc>
```

And I can see that VS Code has a keybindings.json file. I tried this:

```
[{
    "key": "jj",
    "command": "vim.Esc",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}]
```

Also there is a settings.json file, so I tried:

```
{
  "vim.keyboardLayout": "en-US (QWERTY)",
    "vim.insertModeKeyBindings": {
        "j": "vim.Esc"
    }
}
```

Also did not work. So does anyone know how to use the a vim extension with VS Code where I can map `jj` to `Esc` or something else to `Esc` perhaps?

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim ?

Comment: yes, I'm using https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim @sudobangbang

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Add the following to settings.json (open the Command Pallete and search for "User Settings"):

```
"vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
     {
         "before": ["j", "j"],
         "after": ["<esc>"]
     }
]
```

That should do it.

Comment: With current version of VSCodeVim, it works with `<Esc>` instead of `<esc>`.

Comment: can you add another key after "<Esc>" ? like this ```"after": ["<Esc>", "l"]```?

Comment: This has worked for a long time for me, but I'm starting to see weird behavior ([see here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a9mqqyfzykrh75w/Screen%20Recording%202020-05-02%20at%205.34.02%20PM.mov?dl=0)). The first j seems to stay in insert mode and then the second j moves back a character and sometimes deletes the line. Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: @gwintrob All of the sudden I get this mess too.  Did the vim extension auto update or is this a vscode problem?  I remapped to other double letters (ie. "x", "x") and still get the same behavior.

Comment: Nevermind.  I got the fix from your github issue.  [link](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/4787) kudos!

Comment: @st003 Yes, I have mine set to run `"after": ["<Esc>", ":", "w", "<Enter>"]`

Comment: It says these in the README of the GitHub link (https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim).  Other helpful tips can be found there, too!

Comment: This not works for me:

    "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
            "before": [
                "n"
            ],
            "commands": [
                "editor.action.nextMatchFindAction",
            ],
            "after": [
                "<Esc>"
            ],
        },
        {
            "before": [
                "N"
            ],
            "commands": [
                "editor.action.previousMatchFindAction",
            ],
            "after": [
                "<Esc>"
            ],
        },
    ],

Comment: this is working as of Jan 2024, but make sure this is inside curly braces { }

Answer (score 10):

If you running on Linux and have used `setxkbmap` to remap `Esc` to `Caps-Lock` and have problems, I suggest the following workaround [Fix for Esc remapping](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23991#issuecomment-292336504).

The solution is to add the following to your ***User Settings***

> "keyboard.dispatch": "keyCode"

You should save and restart after that
[image]

Answer (score 3):

From [this issue](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/172), I learned that you can use something like

```
{ "key": "j j", "command": "extension.vim_esc", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
```

But it does come with a problem of not being able to use `j` for movement.

PS. I know this is not a complete answer but something to get going.

Comment: This almost works, but when I type j the application freeze waiting for second key.. Have to make sure it only happen when I'm in vim insert mode...