# How to define new keybindings with Visual Studio Code vim extension

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

I've gone over the documentation and the looked at the question:
[How to use vim (key-bindings) with Visual Studio Code vim extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777417/how-to-use-vim-key-bindings-with-visual-studio-code-vim-extension) and I still can't define new keys in the `Vim` extension for `Visual Studio Code`.

I'm trying two things in my `settings.json`. Trying to delete a full tab - instead of just a single space (like vim does) - with backspace.

```
"vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
    {
        "before": "backspace",
        "after": "shift+backspace"
    }
]
```

And also to change between editor panes with `space, w, w` (like using a leader key):

```
"vim.keybindings": [
    {
        "key": ["space", "w", "w"],
        "command": "workbench.action.navigateEditorGroups",
        "when": "editorFocus"
    }
]
```

But I can't get any of those to work.